# HTML5 - form input check

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to understand this input checking example, but it does not seem to work. Two different email inputs don't trigger the error messsage:

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LLS8W/)

html

```
<label>Email:</label>
<input type="email" id="email_addr" name="email_addr">

<label>Repeat Email Address:</label>
<input type="email" id="email_addr_repeat" name="email_addr_repeat" oninput="check(this)">
```

js

```
function check(input) {
 if (input.value != document.getElementById('email_addr').value) {
input.setCustomValidity('The two email addresses must match.');
  } else {
   // input is valid -- reset the error message
   input.setCustomValidity('');
}
}
```

Comment: Those label elements are useless. They neither contain the inputs nor do they have `for` attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that in jsfiddle you have your code inside the `onLoad` event handler.

This way your `check` function (*which exists only inside the `onload` handler scope*) is not accessible from your inline element attributes..

See working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/LLS8W/1/ (*where i have put your code in the `head`. See the top left options of jsfiddle..*)